Photon Fusion BR200 Sample: CS0234 Error When Building WebGL
Issue to Resolve:
I am unable to resolve an error when building with WebGL in Unity using Photon Fusion's BR200 Sample. The error message is CS0234: The type or namespace name could not be found. I haven't found a solution yet.
I would greatly appreciate any ideas from someone knowledgeable about Unity that could help solve this issue.
Error Produced:
Assets\TPSBR\Scripts\Networking\Multiplay\MultiplayManager.cs(22,22): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Multiplay' does not exist in the namespace 'Unity.Services' (are you missing an  assembly reference?)

Relevant Source Code MultiplayManager.cs is below
#if (UNITY_ANDROID || UNITY_IOS ) && !UNITY_EDITOR
using System;
using UnityEngine;

namespace TPSBR
{
    /// <summary>
    /// MultiplayManager works only on server
    /// </summary>
    public sealed class MultiplayManager : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public async void StartMultiplay(SessionRequest sessionRequest, StandaloneConfiguration configuration)
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException();
        }
    }
}
#else
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Unity.Services.Core;
using Unity.Services.Matchmaker.Models;
using Unity.Services.Multiplay;
using UnityEngine;

namespace TPSBR
{
    using System;

    public sealed class MultiplayManager : MonoBehaviour
    {
        // PUBLIC MEMBERS

        public bool QueryProtocol = false;
        public bool Matchmaking = false;
        public bool Backfill = false;
        public int MaxPlayers;
        public MatchmakingResults MatchmakingResults;

        // PRIVATE MEMBERS

        private MultiplayEventCallbacks _multiplayEventCallbacks;
        private IServerEvents _serverEvents;
        private IServerQueryHandler _serverQueryHandler;
        private SessionRequest _sessionRequest;

        private bool _sqpInitialized = false;

        // PUBLIC METHODS

        public async void StartMultiplay(SessionRequest sessionRequest, StandaloneConfiguration configuration)
        {
            _sessionRequest = sessionRequest;
            QueryProtocol = configuration.QueryProtocol;
            Matchmaking = configuration.Matchmaking;
            Backfill = configuration.Backfill;
            MaxPlayers = configuration.MaxPlayers;

            LogServerConfig();

            // Setup allocations
            _multiplayEventCallbacks = new MultiplayEventCallbacks();
            _multiplayEventCallbacks.Allocate += OnAllocate;
            _multiplayEventCallbacks.Deallocate += OnDeallocate;
            _multiplayEventCallbacks.Error += OnError;
            _serverEvents = await MultiplayService.Instance.SubscribeToServerEventsAsync(_multiplayEventCallbacks);

            // It's possible this is a cold start allocation (no event will fire)
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(MultiplayService.Instance.ServerConfig.AllocationId))
            {
                await StartGame();
            }
        }

        // MonoBehaviour INTERFACE

        private async void Awake()
        {
            if (UnityServices.State == ServicesInitializationState.Uninitialized)
            {
                await UnityServices.InitializeAsync();
            }
        }

        private void Update()
        {
            if (QueryProtocol)
            {
                UpdateSqp();
            }
        }

        // PRIVATE METHODS

        private void UpdateSqp()
        {
            if (!_sqpInitialized) InitializeSqp();
            _serverQueryHandler.CurrentPlayers = 1;// (ushort)Global.Networking.PeerCount;
            _serverQueryHandler.UpdateServerCheck();
        }

        private async void InitializeSqp()
        {
            _serverQueryHandler = await MultiplayService.Instance.StartServerQueryHandlerAsync(
                (ushort)_sessionRequest.MaxPlayers,
                _sessionRequest.DisplayName,
                _sessionRequest.GameplayType.ToString().ToLowerInvariant(),
                Application.version,
                "mapname");
            _sqpInitialized = true;
        }

        private void OnError(MultiplayError error)
        {
            LogServerConfig();
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        private void OnDeallocate(MultiplayDeallocation deallocation)
        {
            Debug.Log("Deallocated");
            LogServerConfig();

            MatchmakingResults = null;

            // Hack for now, just exit the application on deallocate
            Application.Quit();
        }

        private async void OnAllocate(MultiplayAllocation allocation)
        {
            Debug.Log("Allocated");
            LogServerConfig();

            await StartGame();
        }

        private async Task StartGame()
        {
            if (!Matchmaking)
            {
                Debug.Log("Matchmaking not enabled, just starting a game");
                Global.Networking.StartGame(_sessionRequest);
                return;
            }

            MatchmakingResults = await MultiplayService.Instance.GetPayloadAllocationFromJsonAs<MatchmakingResults>();
            Debug.Log($"Game produced by matchmaker generator {MatchmakingResults.GeneratorName}, Queue {MatchmakingResults.QueueName}, Pool {MatchmakingResults.PoolName}, BackfillTicketId {MatchmakingResults.BackfillTicketId}");

            _sessionRequest.SessionName = "mm-" + MatchmakingResults.MatchId;
            Global.Networking.StartGame(_sessionRequest);

            while(!Global.Networking.IsConnected)
            {
                await Task.Delay(250);
            }

            if(QueryProtocol)
            {
                Debug.Log("IMultiplayService.ReadyServerForPlayersAsync()");
                await MultiplayService.Instance.ReadyServerForPlayersAsync();
            }
        }

        private void LogServerConfig()
        {
            var serverConfig = MultiplayService.Instance.ServerConfig;
            Debug.Log($"Server ID[{serverConfig.ServerId}], AllocationId[{serverConfig.AllocationId}], Port[{serverConfig.Port}], QueryPort[{serverConfig.QueryPort}], LogDirectory[{serverConfig.ServerLogDirectory}]");
        }
    }
}
#endif

What I Have Tried:
I searched online for a solution, but I found only this discussion, which lacks an answer: https://forum.photonengine.com/discussion/21455/br200-multiplay-and-webgl
I also tried modifying the preprocessor directives to exclude WebGL like this:
#if (UNITY_ANDROID || UNITY_IOS || UNITY_WEBGL) && !UNITY_EDITOR
However, I still haven't found a solution.

Who said it's compatible with webgl?

Photon Fusion supports WebGL build; however, I am unable to find a method to build BR200 (Photon Fusion FPS sample) using WebGL, nor can I find an answer on the web.
https://forum.photonengine.com/discussion/20218/is-photon-fusion-unity-networking-support-the-webgl-multiplayer-game

then you may need to face its not compatible
